# URLDecoder giving unexpected value on UTF-8 url parameter

Tags: java, gwt, utf-8, url-parameters

I'm using `java.net.URLDecoder` to decode a URL parameter that is supposed to be encoded in UTF-8. A quick test reveals I'm getting `?` instead of `∩` in the output. Here's the code:

```
System.out.println(java.net.URLDecoder.decode("A%E2%88%A9B%0AYour+answer+is%3A+3", "UTF-8"));
```

And as output I'm getting:

```
A?B
Your answer is: 3
```

When I plug the string `A%E2%88%A9B%0AYour+answer+is%3A+3` into web decoders (e.g. [here](http://urldecode.org/) or [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)), they get it right:

```
A∩B
Your answer is: 3
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. Is this not actually UTF-8? The string is coming from [com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encodeQueryString()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html#encodeQueryString%28java.lang.String%29), which claims UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Am I guessing right that you're running this on Windows in cmd.exe?

Comment: I'm running through Eclipse and reading console output. Though I originally ran into the problem running code on a Tomcat server.

Comment: Running the above code on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/RsIIKD) produces the second text...

Comment: To me it seems like your font doesn't support the intersection symbol. What font do you use for your output? You can find a list http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2229/index.htm of fonts here.

Comment: Yup, when debugging I can see the intersection symbol as the variable's value. It's the console that's not displaying it correctly. Eclipse uses Consolas, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

As Siguza and VGe0rge pointed out, the Java code was running correctly, but Eclipse's console will not display in UTF-8 by default. A solution to that issue can be found [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/).